# Conditional expression in SnapLogic

Tags: json, nested, mapping, match, snaplogic

I need to check whether or not an entry is present in the data output from a REST call. The JSON output looks something like this:

```
{
  "entity":  {
    "entries":[
      {
        "ID": "1",
        "Pipeline": "Pipeline_1",
        "State":"Completed"
      }
    ],
  "duration":1074,
  "create_time":"2010-10-10"
  }
}
```

I want to check if for example, Pipeline_1 is missing, then I want the pipeline to print out that 'Pipeline_1 is missing', if not - null. I have tried using the ternary `(?)` expression:

```
!$Pipeline.contains ("Pipeline_1") ? "Pipeline_1 is missing" : null && !$Pipeline.contains ("Pipeline_2") ? "Pipeline_2 is missing" : null
```

I'm having problems with the syntax and I just can't get it right using this method, because it only processes the first query.

I have also tried using the `match` method, but haven't had success with it either:

```
match $Pipeline {
    $Pipeline!=("Pipeline_1") => 'Pipeline_1 is missing',
    $Pipeline!=("Pipeline_2") => 'Pipeline_2 is missing',
    _ => 'All of the pipelines have been executed successfully'
}
```

I have to check for multiple conditions. Any suggestions on how I should nest the conditional expressions? Thank you in advance.

Comment: It is not exactly clear what final output you are expecting.

Comment: Also, how are you getting `$Pipeline` in the root if it is part of an object in the `entries[]` array. Are you splitting with the expression `$entity.entries[*]` before doing your validation?

Comment: If you are splitting, then how can you validate just based on one object? And if you are not splitting, neither of the shared expressions will work.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are not splitting the array `$entity.entries[*]` and processing the incoming document as is, following is a possible solution.

**Test Pipeline:**

[image: test pipeline]

**Input:**

```
{
    "entity": {
        "entries": [
            {
                "ID": "1",
                "Pipeline": "Pipeline_1",
                "State": "Completed"
            }
        ],
        "duration": 1074,
        "create_time": "2010-10-10"
    }
}
```

**Expression:**

```
{
    "Pipeline_1": $entity.entries.reduce((a, c) => c.Pipeline == "Pipeline_1" || a, false),
    "Pipeline_2": $entity.entries.reduce((a, c) => c.Pipeline == "Pipeline_2" || a, false)
}.values().reduce((a, c) => c && a, true) ? "All pipelines executed successfully" : "Pipeline(s) missing"
```

**Output:**

[image]

---

If you **don't** want to do it in a single expression, then you can use a **Conditional** snap like as follows.

[image]

Following is the output of the **Conditional** snap.

[image]

Then you can process it as you please.